# PayPal API - discount?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm trying to get a discount to apply to a shopping cart I've written. I'm using the `Adaptive API` system, but I can't seem to get it right. I've tried it in the **SetPaymentOptions** call:

```
      'receiverOptions' => [
                             {
                               'receiver' => {
                                               'email' => 'foo@live.co.uk'
                                             },
                               'invoiceData' => {
                                                  'totalShipping' => '8.00',
                                                  'totalTax' => 0,
                                                  'item' => [
                                                              {
                                                                'itemPrice' => '15.00',
                                                                'name' => 'Alice in Wonderland Mechanism Necklace',
                                                                'price' => '15',
                                                                'itemCount' => 1
                                                              },
                                                              {
                                                                'itemPrice' => '30.00',
                                                                'name' => '110 Year Old Unicorn Dial Necklace',
                                                                'price' => '30',
                                                                'itemCount' => 1
                                                              }
                                                            ],
                                                  'discount' => '0.15'
                                                }
                             }
                           ],
      'requestEnvelope' => {
                             'errorLanguage' => 'en_US',
                             'detailLevel' => 'ReturnAll'
                           },
      'payKey' => 'AP-2F6415163M814733M',
      'SenderOptions' => {
                           'requireShippingAddressSelection' => bless( do{\(my $o = 1)}, 'JSON::XS::Boolean' )
                         }
    };
```

..and even tried it in the initial **Pay** call - but neither seem to recognise the discount (and apply it).

```
     'currencyCode' => 'GBP',
      'requestEnvelope' => {
                             'errorLanguage' => 'en_US',
                             'detailLevel' => 'ReturnAll'
                           },
      'cancelUrl' => 'https://sitedev.net/',
      'discount' => '0.15',
      'actionType' => 'CREATE',
      'ipnNotificationUrl' => 'https://sitedev.net/cgi-bin/ipn.cgi',
      'returnUrl' => 'https://sitedev.net/myorders',
      'reverseAllParallelPaymentsOnError' => bless( do{\(my $o = 0)}, 'JSON::XS::Boolean' ),
      'receiverList' => {
                          'receiver' => [
                                          {
                                            'email' => 'foo@live.co.uk',
                                            'amount' => '53.00',
                                            'invoiceId' => '47',
                                            'paymentType' => 'GOODS'
                                          }
                                        ]
                        }
    };
```

**UPDATE:** Mmm ok - still having issues with this!

```
                         'item' => [
                                     {
                                       'itemPrice' => '25.00',
                                       'name' => 'Cryptex - 16Gb USB Drive',
                                       'price' => '25',
                                       'itemCount' => 1
                                     },
                                     {
                                       'name' => 'Special Discount',
                                       'price' => '-2.50',
                                       'itemCount' => 1
                                     },
                                     {
                                       'itemPrice' => '5.00',
                                       'name' => 'Shipping',
                                       'price' => '5.00',
                                       'itemCount' => 1
                                     }
                                   ]
```

Thats the values I'm passing in, yet at the cart end, it shows as:

```
 Steampunk Junkies £27.50
 Cryptex - 16Gb USB Drive
 £25.00
 Shipping
 £5.00

 £0.00
```

The weird thing - is that the discount IS being applied... just not shown???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm curious where you see that there's a "discount" parameter even available in these calls..??  It's not listed in the API reference for [Pay](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) or [SetPaymentOptions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/SetPaymentOptions_API_Operation/).

What you'll need to do is add the discount as a line item in SetPaymentOptions with a negative amount.  So it would be an extra line item with -0.15 as the value.  You could name the item "discount" or whatever you want, but again, there is no actual discount parameter available in these API's.

Comment: Ah thats a good idea - not sure why I didn't think of that :) I was seeing the `discount` param in the other API (that you pass along in a URL, for the "standard" payments)... but just assumed it would also work in the JSON. Their API docs are a bit lame for the Adaptive stuff :( Will give that a go now, and then up-vote if it works =)

Comment: Mmm ok, that didn't work - you get an error when trying to use a negative: `ERROR: Invalid request parameter: itemPrice cannot be negative at /var/home/user/site.net/cgi-bin/admin/Want/Cart.pm line 437.`

Comment: Ah, my mistake - it didn't like the `itemPrice` being defined... if I just used the `price` param, then it works fine. Thanks!