# PayPal Issues When adding discounted products

Tags: paypal

I am hoping someone can help me.

I have discount sets on my products to apply a percentage discount when ordering a certain amount of one produt.

I am having issues when my site sends the total to PayPal as I am gettign the following error (example) -

```
num products: 2
array(2) {
    [0]=> string(5) "38649"
    [1]=> string(5) "40119" }

discount: g total: 326.02

array(2) {
    [0]=> string(28) "API_L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0"
    [1]=> string(28) "API_L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME1"
}
name: 101.6 x 152.4mm Direct Thermal Labels - Permanent Adhesive Select core size:: 76mm; - Multibuy!
name: 110 x 45mm Thermal Transfer Labels - Freezer Adhesive Select core size:: 76mm; - Multibuy!

&RETURNURL=https://www.labelmetrics.co.uk/store/paypal_return.php
&CANCELURL=https://www.labelmetrics.co.uk/store/view_cart.php
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=GBP
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=326.02
&BRANDNAME=
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=326.02
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT=
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT=
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=101.6 x 152.4mm Direct Thermal Labels - Permanent Adhesive Select core size:: 76mm; - Multibuy!
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0=
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=13.81
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=20
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT0=0.00
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME1=110 x 45mm Thermal Transfer Labels - Freezer Adhesive Select core size:: 76mm; - Multibuy!
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC1=
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT1=19.16
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY1=6
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT1=0.00

SetExpressCheckout failed: Array (
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2018-09-06T09:11:59Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => a7547fbde80c6
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 64.0
    [BUILD] => 48666477
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10413
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts.
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
)
```

Has anyone seen this before and can anyone help?

Comment: Hi, Sorry I am not techinical enough to do this.This can be recreated on our webiste if you are able to do this?

Comment: I don't know the PayPal API well enough myself sorry. The error is this "The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts": can you capture the data you're posting to PayPal with the individual cart items and the total and see what's gone wrong, e.g. the line item is discounted but the total isn't, or vice versa? (Or is that the L_PAYMENTREQUEST values in your post?) Maybe then you can look through the code that's generating it and find the bug.

Comment: OK, so you have 20 packs of direct labels @ 13.81 each = £276.20 and 6 thermal transfer labels @ 19.16 each = £114.96, so £391.16, but you've told PayPal the total is £326.02 - approx 1/6 off? It looks like you haven't passed an explanation of the difference on to PayPal, so it's rejecting the request. I don't know if you can tell PayPal that there's a global discount, or if you have to discount the individual items, so I'm not sure what to suggest now.

Comment: Here's [an old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26819157/243245) that says you can add the discount (if it's not per-item) as a separate row with a negative price, as long as you just have a price not an item-price.